# have any body faced the error like this in netbeans

Tags: jsp, netbeans

I am trying to run a web project in netbeans IDE, when i run the project i got the error like this,

```
Warning: Could not find file ${libs.exceptionhandler-runtime.classpath} to copy.
```

how to resolve this error.

Comment: if maybe you have some fault in your class path, you should check your class path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstall NetBeans 
[7.4](https://netbeans.org/downloads/)
[8.0 (RC)](http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/netbeans/8.0/rc/)